# c# how check if the form is already open in compact framework

Tags: c#, compact-framework

```
FormCollection fc = Application.OpenForms;

foreach (Form frm in fc)
{
//iterate through
}
```

OR

```
Form fc = Application.OpenForms["FORMNAME"]; if (fc != null) fc.Close(); fm.Show();
```

but non of this works in compact framework 3.5. How can i check if form is already opened in CF 3.5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Barry wrote, you will have to do it yourself. Easiest way is to use a dictionary. Your key can be a form's type, its name, or whatever you need.

```
private static readonly Dictionary<string, MyForm> _dict 
    = new Dictionary<string, MyForm>();

public MyForm CreateOrShow(string formName)
{
    Form f = null;
    if (!_dict.TryGetValue(formName, out f))
    {
        f = new MyForm();
        _dict.Add(formName, f);
    } 
    return f;
}
```

Or, if you want to support multiple form types and want to avoid casting, use a generic method:

```
private static readonly Dictionary<string, Form> _dict 
    = new Dictionary<string, Form>();

public T CreateOrShow<T>(string formName) where T : Form, new()
{
    Form f = null;
    if (!_dict.TryGetValue(formName, out f))
    {
        f = new T();
        _dict.Add(formName, f);
    }
    return (T)f;
}

public T CreateOrShow<T>(string formName, Func<T> ctor) where T : Form
{
    Form f = null;
    if (!_dict.TryGetValue(formName, out f))
    {
        f = ctor();
        _dict.Add(formName, f);
    }
    return (T)f;
}
```

There are two generic overloads. One of them is used like this:

```
// use this if MyFormType has a parameterless constructor
var form = CreateOrShow<MyFormType>("Form1");
```

or, if you need to pass parameters to your form during init:

```
// use this if MyFormType accepts parameters in constructor
var form = CreateOrShow<MyFormType>("Form1", () => new MyFormType(someData));
```

Comment: var form = (PregledZaslonov)Forms.CreateOrShow("PregledZaslonov"); form.Show(); or if i use generic method i always get InvalidCastException. Why?

Comment: @senzacionale: sorry, I will fix it now.

Comment: @senzacionale: ok, done. The problem was in line `f = new Form();`, because it always instantiated a base `Form` instance, instead of your `T` generic class. I've added an additional overload in case you also need to supply parameters during construction.

Answer (score 1):

The `Application.OpenForms` collection doesn't exist in the Compact Framework.

You would have to roll your own collection and keep track of them that way.

There is [nice tutorial here](http://dandohotaru.blogspot.com/2007/11/caching-opened-forms-in-net-compact.html) that explains how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a static boolean field on all your forms. Then you'd have to create a couple methods to toggle it, and bind the Opening and Closing event handlers to it. Not the most elegant solution admittedly.

```
partial class Form1 : Form
{
    static bool IsFormOpen;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Load += SignalFormOpen;
        this.FormClosing += SignalFormClosed;
    }

    void SignalFormOpen(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        IsFormOpen = true;
    }

    void SignalFormClosed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        IsFormOpen = false;
    }
}
```

Either that or make a collection of forms somewhere, and each time a form loads make it store a reference to itself in it, and iterate against that to check if the form is open/exists